# How to use Charles proxy to map a local file without causing CORS error?

Tags: proxy, xmlhttprequest, charles-proxy

I am working on a web application that makes an XHR call to a particular endpoint that returns search results e.g. [www.foo.com/search](http://www.foo.com/search)

The json response from the endpoint will be changing so I would like to mock this new response for local development using a local proxy , Charles in my case. I know I could mock the data in the code in the app but I would really like to mock this at the network level.

Charles has a feature to `Map Local` which captures the requests and returns the contents of a local file in the body of the response. This is not working for me. When I try to make the request in my local dev application, running on `localhost:3000`, I get a CORS error. I can see the OPTIONS preflight request succeed but the POST request fails.

Is it possible to get around the CORS error using Charles?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here, you are modifying the response of `foo.com/search` but the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header still remains the same (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin=foo.com`). Due to this, the localhost:3000 is throwing CORS error here.

**Bypass CORS**: To bypass this error, you first need to create a Header Modification which updates the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value to `*`. This can be achieved using [this Header Rule](https://app.requestly.io/rules#sharedList/1683205545881-Bypass-CORS) in Requestly.

[image]

**Modify Response**: After bypassing the CORS error, now you can use your Map Local Rule, which will modify the response of the Request. Here's a [Requestly Response Rule](https://app.requestly.io/shared-lists/viewer/1683203073237-Modify-Response) for same

[image: response rule]

Comment: I tried the Requestly Map Local feature. It didn't work. Same CORS problems as Charles.

Comment: @spinners Updated the answer. Understood the question wrong before

Answer (score 0):

Within Charles Proxy you can use `Rewrite` to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*` header. You will still need to`Map Remote` to your local as you have been, and then enable `Rewrite` on your localhost location to append the header.

[Rewrite config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ricMo.jpg)

[Access control origin config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nklO6.png)